# delete from delta parquet files in storage gen2

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Using the below code, I can read from delta but not sure how to delete from it
tried running delete but I get error.

This is what I have and do you see how to run delete please?

Thanks

```py
df = spark.read.parquet(
   f"abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net{delta_folder_path}")

df_today = df.filter("year=" + str(yearNo) + " and month=" + 
  str(monthNo) + " and day=" + str(dayNo))

display(df_today) --> displays correctly

df_today.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_presentation")
```

Then in another notebook cell I am using

```
%sql
--select * from vw_presentation --this select works fine

delete from vw_presentation where name = 'xyz'
```

> error --> Error in SQL statement: AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for DeleteFromTable

I even tried it this way but still gives error:

```
%sql

delete from delta.'/presentation/delivery/year=2022/month=05/day=26' 
   where name = 'xyz'
```

[image: delta parquet structure]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for DeleteFromTable In Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919988/assertionerror-assertion-failed-no-plan-for-deletefromtable-in-databricks)

Comment: I know I shoukd use, %sql delete from delta.... but i can not get the path right. The delta files are in curated/foldername/year=2002/month=05/day=26

Comment: In addition it seems I can not do an update like below:
This is what I have now but not sure why I can not update the table:
df_data = spark.read.parquet(f"abfss://{container_name}@storageName.dfs.core.windows.net{delta_folder_path}")

display(df_data) --> display data

df_data.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("tbl_data")

Then in another cell
%sql
select * from tbl_data -> shows data
but the follwoing does not work
update tbl_data where name = 'xyz'
error -> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: UPDATE destination only supports Delta sources.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your source table is in the Parquet format, not in Delta. And Parquet doesn't support delete and update operations. If you want to perform such operations, you have two choices:

- Convert Parquet files to Delta using the [CONVERT TO DELTA](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-convert-to-delta.html) SQL command
- Use Spark code to perform what you need:

  - Read full dataset
  - Filter out data that you want to leave: `df.filter("name != 'xyz'")`
  - Write data back using `.mode("overwrite")`

Comment: But I thought I amusing delta, no?. See screenshot I posted previously. Thanks

Comment: But why are you reading as .parquet?

Comment: ok, let me get this right. as per my screen-shot above, I am using delta parquet, right?

Comment: No. Delta and parquet are different formats, although Delta is based on parquet… So you need to read data as delta, while you are reading as parquet

Comment: I am unable to put a screen-shot here so I describe a few things I am doing:
1-
In one project using ADF, I place data in sink as  a single .parquet file.
The structure in this storage folder
.parquet
commited
started
success
2-
IN another project, in a folder where I place the data I use Delta inline dataset which places the data in the folder as _delta_log with a lot of .parquet partitioned files

Question:
Are you saying in point number 2 above, I am not using delta parquet files?